# C++11 conditional expression on std::greater and std::less got error of different types

Tags: c++, c++11

The following codes related to conditional expression:

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
uchar data[100];
// assign something to array[] here
uchar *start = data;
uchar *end = data+100;
bool cond = f();  // f() could return true or false
uchar *itr = std::upper_bound(start, end, uchar(20), 
                cond? std::greater<uchar>() : std::less<uchar>());
```

got an error like this:

```
error: operands to ?: have different types 
‘std::greater<unsigned char>’ and ‘std::less<unsigned char>’
```

Is this a compiler bug? In my instinct, the two functor should have the same type.

Comment: And what type is that?

Comment: I just changed `char *itr` to `uchar *itr`. I assumed that was the intent. (It's not relevant to the main question, but is important to get this code to compile)

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, it's a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functors in C++ do not traditionally share a type.  This makes it easy for the compiler to understand *exactly* which functor is being called, and causes a performance boost.

There is a mechanism in C++ called type erasure.  This is where you forget what makes two types different, and only remembers what makes them the same.

The most common kind of type erasure in C++ is `std::function`.  This function here type erases a stateless template that takes two `T const&` and returns a `bool`:

```
template<class T, template<class...>class Z>
std::function< bool(T const&, T const&) >
comp() { return Z<T>{}; }
```

we can then take your code and do this:

```
uchar *itr = std::upper_bound(start, end, uchar(20), 
            cond? comp<uchar, std::greater>() : comp<uchar, std::less>());
```

or alternatively:

```
template<class T>
using comp_sig = bool(T const&, T const&);

template<class T, template<class...>class Z>
comp_sig<T>* comp() {
  return [](T const& lhs, T const& rhs)->bool{
    return Z<T>{}(lhs, rhs);
  };
}
```

which gives you function pointers that call `less` or `greater` as required.  This version might be slightly easier for compilers to optimize than the `std::function` one, as compilers are really good at optimizing constant function pointers.

Answer (score 5):

`std::greater` and `std::less` are different types (just as different as `std::string` and `std::unordered_map`). They only provide same interface (`operator()`).

Conditional operator `cond ? expr1 : expr2` requires, that `expr1` and `expr2` is of the same type (or one is implicitly convertible to another) and that is not your case.

You can use

```
char *itr;
if (cond)
    itr = std::upper_bound(start, end, uchar(20), std::greater<uchar>{});
else
    itr = std::upper_bound(start, end, uchar(20), std::less<uchar>{});
```

Or if you do not want to have two almost same lines, you can help yourself with generic lambda

```
auto upper_bound = [&](const auto& cmp){
    return std::upper_bound(start, end, uchar(20), cmp);
};
if (cond)
    itr = upper_bound(std::greater<uchar>{});
else
    itr = upper_bound(std::less<uchar>{});
```

Comment: I would just use `auto&&`, because who cares if it is `const`.  And `itr = cond?upper_bound(std::greater<char>{}):upper_bound(std::less<char>{});` would more closely match the OP's original code.

Answer (score 2):

Functors are just regular types. `std::greater<uchar>` is a completely different type from `std:less<uchar>`. Just like how `std::vector<uchar>` is different from `std::set<uchar>`, even though their properties are similar!

You can achieve what you want to achieve if you move your ternary operator a bit though:

```
char *itr = cond ?
    std::upper_bound(start, end, uchar(20), std::greater<uchar>()) :
    std::upper_bound(start, end, uchar(20), std::less<uchar>());
```

It's slightly more duplication, but just as readable and will compile.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not, as it is said it is different types. std::less is something like this :

```
template <class T>
struct Less
{
      bool operator()(const T & t1, const T & t2) ..
};
```

Comment: Good answer, but solving the OP's problem as well as answering questions is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

First, these two functors don't have the same type, even though they have same type of opetor(), which is, after template instantiation,

```
bool operator()(uchar lhs, uchar rhs)
```

Similarly, just because `vector<int>` and `deque<int>` have same type of operator[] obviously doesn't mean they have the same type.

Back to your code, if you are able to use C++11, a simple & elegant solution is using lambda:

```
char *itr = std::upper_bound(start, end, uchar(20),  
            [cond](uchar lhs, uchar rhs) { return cond ? lhs > rhs : lhs < rhs); }
```

Otherwise, just writ a straightforward functor

```
class F{  
public:  
    explicit F(bool cond): m_cond(cond) {}
    bool operator(uchar lhs, uchar rhs) { return m_cond ? lhs > rhs : lhs < rhs); }  
private:
    bool m_cond;
};
```

Lastly, lambda is a pretty handy tool, I suggest you get to know more about it.
[What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)
[When to use functors over lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256062/when-to-use-functors-over-lambdas)

Answer (score 0):

Convert both of them to lambdas (non-capture, non-generic). In that case, their types are still different, but they both convert naturally to a plain old function pointer `bool (*) (uchar, uchar)` and therefore the `?:` works

```
uchar *itr = std::upper_bound(start, end, uchar(20),
                 cond?
                 ([](uchar x, uchar y){return std::greater<uchar>{}(x,y);})
                 :
                 ([](uchar x, uchar y){return std::less   <uchar>{}(x,y);})
             );
```

(This works for me on clang 3.5 and g++ 5.3, but I'm not sure how portable this is. Should I use unary `+` to force the conversion to the function pointer?

Comment: This will probably break on MSVC because their lambdas have *four* implicit conversions to function pointers (one per calling convention), but I haven't tested it.